# Can I make a question more encompassing?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

One of my [questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/121491/what-is-the-drift-attribute-for-a-car) is not getting any answers so far. I did additional research and still cannot answer it myself. I'm considering widening the scope of the question as I am ultimately also interested in other closely related aspects of the game.

Is this acceptable? Is there an argument against it (such as lessening chances of getting an answer to my original more specific question)? Is it better for me to create a new, more general, question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have that game but the scope of the original question seems just fine to me. If anything, if you're really aching for answer, I'd either make the question less detailed and thus easier to answer or place a bounty on it.

Comment: I was thinking of the bounty but considered how it would "cost" a quarter of what I have, too. Seems like I do not have to worry about this anymore though, thanks to you. This is _very_ appreciated! I would also have made the question less focused (and ask about attributes in general), but it seems it is getting answers now, so this shouldn't be necessary anymore. I will let it run for a few days.

Comment: @leokhorn Let me know what answer should get the bounty in the comments area in this post please.

Comment: No other better answers have appeared and I think it's been long enough, so you may reward Turtleweezard. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: *Does a bounty dance*